# Perl time vs. Unix date output inconsistency

Tags: perl, unix, unix-timestamp

I am a total beginner in Perl and trying my first Perl script to convert time information in epoch-seconds to a specific format. I understand that month Jan = 0 and year 1900 = 0 in Perl from other Stack Overflow questions. Even after adjusting for them, I am not seeing identical outputs between Unix and Perl.

Here is what I tried and got.

Unix:

```
date -d @915149280
```

gives me:

**Thu Dec 31 19:08:00 EST 1998**

Perl:

```
$time = 915149280;
($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = gmtime($time);
$year = $year + 1900;
$mon = $mon + 1;
print "Formated time = $mday/$mon/$year $hour:$min:$sec $weekday[$wday]\n";
```

gives me:

**Formatted time = 1/1/1999 0:8:0 Fri**

Is there a mistake in the Perl lines? What should I do to get the same output as the date command? (not the formatting part, but time).

I am not looking for all the fields. Only the year is important to me.

Comment: time zones. You're off by exactly 5 hours. ANYTIME you get a time difference that's an exact number of hours different, it's pretty much 99.999999% a timezone issue

Comment: Apart from the time zone difference, you should use `printf` with `"%02d"` to print most of the fields.

Comment: @KeithThompson: no, s/he should use POSIX::strftime (or some other module's strftime) to print all the fields :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the time difference rather than the format difference, since your Perl code doesn't even attempt to replicate that format.

Use [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) instead of [`gmtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html).  The `date` command uses your local time by default.  Notice that it says "EST", but `gmtime` returns UTC, a 5 hour difference.

You should also consider using a module to handle the date formatting.  But that won't prevent confusion between local time and UTC.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the time difference. Btw, thank you very much for your explanation. Using localtime solved my problem. As I said, this is my first perl script, perhaps even the last.

Answer (score 1):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been included with Perl for almost seven years and will make your time and date code far easier.

```
use Time::Piece;

my $then = gmtime(915149280);
print $then->strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %a'); # produces 01-01-1999 00:08:00 Fri
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this considerably easier by using `strftime` from the [POSIX](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX) module.

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -le 'print strftime "%a %b %d %T %Y",localtime(915149280)'
```

Thu Dec 31 16:08:00 1998

The `POSIX` module has been a [core](http://perlpunks.de/corelist/version?module=POSIX) module since 1994.  By using an explicit import list, you avoid loading some 500+ symbols that you don't require.